# Combinatorics: Distributing coins among three persons

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

> Seven different coins are to be divided among three persons. If no two of the persons receive the same number of coins but each receive at least one coin & none is left over, then the number of ways in which the division may be made is:
>
> (A) 420
>
> (B) 630
>
> (C) 710
>
> (D) None of these

The answer given is option (B)

**This is how I solved it**

Using inclusion-exclusion principle, distribution of 7 different coins into 3 different groups (of unknown size), such that no group is empty.

$$3^7-^3C_1(3-1)^7+^3C_2(3-2)^7=1806$$ But this also includes the counting of groups with any two same number of coins, thus we need to subtract that from the above term, let it be $K$.

The only possible case with "If no two of the persons receive the same number of coins" is 2 same, 2 same, 1 different, these are $$(3,3,1), (2,2,3),(1,1,5)$$ Thus the corresponding arrangements are:-$$\frac{7!}{3!3!1!} , \frac{7!}{2!2!3!}, \frac{7!}{1!1!5!}$$Sum of these three $K=392$

Thus answer $=1806-392=1414$

But the answer given is option (B). Where am I wrong? How would you solve the problem?

Comment: I have added my answer to my question which points the error in my method

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got the error in my method so I thought to write answer myself.

As I already mentioned the three cases that needs to be subtracted and named it $K$, the problem was that I already selected that first two groups will be same and the third will be different, but in reality we need to arrange these as $\frac{3!}{2!1!}=3$, hence the terms 
$$\frac{7!}{3!3!1!} , \frac{7!}{2!2!3!}, \frac{7!}{1!1!5!}$$needs to be multiplied by three and then added thus $K$ will be $3\times392=1176$

And hence the answer will be $1806-1176=630$

Answer (score 7):

I would reason as follows :

The only distribution that satisfies the conditions is $(1, 2, 4)$.
This gives rise to $\binom{7}{4} \times \binom{3}{2} \times \binom{1}{1}$ arrangements : first we choose the 4-coin group, then among the 3 remaining coins we choose the 2-coin group, then among the 1 coin left we "choose" the 1-coin group. That gives 105 possibilities.

Now that we have separated the coins into three unequal (in terms of cardinal), non-empty groups, we assign these three groups to the three people : there are $3 !$ possibilities.

Total is therefore $105 \times 6 = 630$.

Answer (score 4):

The only possible split up for $7$ as a sum of $3$ distinct positive integers with summation $7$ is: $$7=1+2+4$$

There are $3!$ permutations of $(1,2,4)$.

And if e.g. the first person gets $1$, the second gets $2$ and the third gets $4$ coins then there are $\frac{7!}{1!2!4!}$ distinct ways to divide the coins.

So eventually we find:$$3!\times\frac{7!}{1!2!4!}=630$$ possibilities.

Answer (score 1):

The conditions that everyone receives a different number, but no-one receives none, mean that the only possibility is that the coins are split $1,2,4$ in some order among the people.

There are $7$ ways to choose the single coin, and $\binom 62$ ways to choose a pair of coins from what's left, then $3!$ ways to assign the three people to the three sets of coins. So the answer is $7\times 15\times 6$.